# Side of a square

Tags: geometry, circles

How to find the side length of this type of squares if $A$ and $B$ are given

[image: FIg. 1]

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Generally speaking, questions should explain the effort that you have put into solving the problem, so that your potential answerers do not waste their time explaining to you things that you already know.

Comment: Where is the center of the inner circle?\

Comment: I guess $a$ and $b$ are given, and you want to find length of square side. if that small circle has center on line $x_1 x_2$ try pitagoras theorem

Comment: That should not matter @zz20s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Power of a Point on the pair of intersecting chords in the smaller circle. If we call the half-side length $x$ (for simplicity sake), we have that
$$(x - b)^{2} = x(x - a)$$
$$x^{2} - 2bx + b^{2} = x^{2} - ax$$
$$2bx - ax = b^{2}$$
$$x = \frac{b^{2}}{2b - a}.$$

The side length then is
$$2x = \boxed{\frac{2b^{2}}{2b - a}}.$$

Comment: Ah! Very clever answer! all this time I was trying to use the law of sines or cosines. +1!

Comment: Thanks! Though that would take a bit more computation, it would still produce the same answer @zz20s

Comment: Sorry, your solution doesn't work. Suppose $A = 5$ and $B=7$. In that case correct side length is $18$. Here your solution fails.

Comment: And how did you come up with that answer? How do you know it is correct? @rabinra singh

Comment: As suggested in my earlier comment, your question should tell us what you already know. Clearly you have some formula or computation in mind for the example $a=5$, $b=7$, which you should include as part of your question.

Comment: I failed to some up with any type of solution. But in the statement this sample case was given.

Comment: But @rabinrasingh, how can $b$ be greater than $a$?

Comment: @rabinra singh That "solution" is bogus. Just because $9 - a$ and $9 - b$ appear to be in a Pythagorean triple doesn't mean that that is the answer. Examine your answer carefully, using actual geometry.

Comment: No, the side is not 18 when a = 5 and b = 7 [sic].  It's 50/3, K. Jiang is right.